# c++11 not recognized in header file

Tags: c++, c++11

In my C++ program, c++11 features like non-static data member initializers and scoped enums work without warnings in my main.cpp file. When I try to use these c++11 features in my header file, I get compiler warnings `only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]`

main.cpp file:

```
#include "Fruit.h"
#include "Fruit.cpp"

class Vegetable
{
    enum class VegetableType
    {
        Potato,
        Spinach,
        Broccoli,
        Carrot,
        Tomato,
        Pea,
        Cabbage
    };

    Vegetable(const VegetableType& vegetableType, const int& x, const int& y = 0);
    virtual ~Vegetable();

private:
    VegetableType currentVegetableType = VegetableType::Pea;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    bool isTastey = false;
};

Vegetable::Vegetable(const VegetableType& vegetableType, const int& x, const int& y)
{
    currentVegetableType = vegetableType;
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Fruit.h file:

```
#ifndef FRUIT_H_
#define FRUIT_H_

class Fruit
{
    enum class FruitType
    {
        Berry,
        Pear,
        Samara,
        Drupe,
        Nucule,
        Pome,
        Pineapple
    };

    Fruit(const FruitType& fruitType, const int& x, const int& y = 0);
    virtual ~Fruit();

private:
    FruitType currentFruitType = FruitType::Pear;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    bool isTastey = false;
};

#endif // FRUIT_H
```

Fruit.cpp file:

```
#include "Fruit.h"

Fruit::Fruit(const FruitType& fruitType, const int& x, const int& y)
{
    currentFruitType = fruitType;
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}
```

CDT Build Console Output:

```
12:19:26 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project EclipseBug ****
make all 
Building file: ../Fruit.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"Fruit.d" -MT"Fruit.d" -o "Fruit.o" "../Fruit.cpp"
In file included from ../Fruit.cpp:1:0:
../Fruit.h:6:2: warning: scoped enums only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
  enum class FruitType
  ^
../Fruit.h:21:42: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
  FruitType currentFruitType = FruitType::Pear;
                                          ^
../Fruit.h:22:10: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
  int x = 0, y = 0;
subdir.mk:21: recipe for target 'Fruit.o' failed
          ^
../Fruit.h:22:17: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
  int x = 0, y = 0;
                 ^
../Fruit.h:23:18: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
  bool isTastey = false;
                  ^
../Fruit.h:21:31: error: ‘FruitType’ is not a class or namespace
  FruitType currentFruitType = FruitType::Pear;
                               ^
make: *** [Fruit.o] Error 1

12:19:26 Build Finished (took 63ms)
```

Why does c++11 work in main.cpp but not in Fruit.h? How can enable c++11 in my Fruit.h file? My 'other flags' under **Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > Miscellaneous** are: `-c -std=c++11 -fmessage-length=0`

I am using Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) as my IDE.

Comment: There is no `--std=c++11` for `Fruit.cpp` compilation. It looks like you may've enabled c++11 support only for main.cpp file. You should set project-wide settings instead (that is select project node in workspace explorer first and then go to properties).

Comment: @VTT I set the `-std=c++11` flag in 'Properties for my_program'. Shouldn't that affect the whole project?

Comment: Modify your `Makefile` appropriately

Comment: Don't `#include` your `.cpp` file. Compile that separately and link it in.

Comment: @PhilippHoehnkingphilippiii  _not_ enabling this option for all your cpp files is dangerous, you really want the same options for all your source files in the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Do *NOT* "include" the Fruit.cpp source file in your "main.cpp".
   Compile Fruit.cpp separately.  That's what your linker is for :)
2. Eclipse > project preferences > Settings > C/C++ Compiler > Miscellaneous > Other Flags >
   <= add "-std=c++11"
3. Make sure your makefile also has "-std=c++11"

Comment: The 'only available with c++11' errors disappeared but I am getting `undefined reference to 'vtable for Vegetable'` on line 26 of main.cpp and `undefined reference to 'vtable for Fruit', multiple definition of 'Fruit::Fruit(Fruit::FruitType const&, int const&, int 
  const&)'` on line 3 of Fruit.cpp

Comment: 1) Make sure all methods in "Fruit" and "Vegetable" and implemented in their respective .cpp source files.  2) Make sure Fruit.cpp and Vegetable.cpp are included in your Makefile, and both are linked in to your executable.  ALSO: remember that C++ members are *PRIVATE* by default.  You might want to add "public" to your class definition!